# convert date from json format to other formats in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Can anyone tell me how to convert date from Json data to normal date format in sencha.

```
var df = this.dateFormat;

if (!v) {
    return v;
}
if (Ext.isDate(v)) {
    return v;
}
if (df) {
    if (df == 'timestamp') {
        return new Date(v * 1000);
    }
    if (df == 'time') {
        return new Date(parseInt(v, 10));
    }
    return Date.parseDate(v, df);
}
var parsed = Date.parse(v);
return parsed ? new Date(parsed) : null;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ext.Date class is what you're looking for. Try something like:

```
 var parsed = Ext.Date.parse(valueFromJSON, "Y-m-d g:i:s A");
```

The [Ext.Date.parse](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) method returns a Date.